# Bind to textarea.text in a separate component file

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I have a create characters component with a tabnavigator and textarea. In my main app I want to save the textarea id - mainchar text to the  tag. I tried dotnotation, nothing, I tried import components.CreateCharacter; and still nothing, and tried some other options found on the net but can't get this to work.

Note, the code works fine if I call components in the main app, so the code works fine it is just the calling of the component (CreateCharacters) in the components folder. The components folder is in the src folder. Here is the code:

```
Main.mxml
<fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import components.CreateCharacters
            [Bindable]
                public var xmlData:XML=<ROOTS></ROOTS>;

            public function sav_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                    var fr:FileReference = new FileReference(); 

                    var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                    var newXmlRow:XML=<ROOTS>

                    <TXT>{components.CreateCharacters.mainchar.text}</TXT>// The problem lies with this line
                    <TXTA>{txt2.text}</TXTA>
                    <DTF>{txt3.text}</DTF>
                    </ROOTS>;
                    ba.writeMultiByte(newXmlRow, 'utf-8');
                    fr.save(ba);
                }

            private var openedFile:File;

            private function open_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
                openedFile = new File();
                openedFile.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, file_select);
                openedFile.browseForOpen("Please select a file...");
            }

            private function file_select(event:Event):void {
                if(openedFile != null && openedFile.exists){
                    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
                    fileStream.open(openedFile, FileMode.READ);
                    var readXML:XML = XML(fileStream.readUTFBytes(fileStream.bytesAvailable));
                    fileStream.close();
                    trace(readXML.toString());
                    CreateCaracters.maichar.text = readXML.TXT;
                    txt2.text = readXML.TXTA;
                    txt3.text = readXML.DTF;
                }
                trace(event);
            }


        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <net:FileReference id="fileReference" />
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Image x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="50" scaleMode="stretch"
             source="assets/imaginationFly.png"/>
    <s:Image x="12" y="1" source="assets/ECWDove.png"/>
    <mx:TabNavigator x="1" y="49" width="100%" height="100%" backgroundColor="#7EB7C5"
                     chromeColor="#85B5BF">
        <s:NavigatorContent width="100%" height="100%" label="Start">
            <s:TextArea id="txt2" x="57" y="29"/>
        </s:NavigatorContent>

        <s:NavigatorContent id="Characters" width="100%" height="100%" label="Characters">
        <components:CreateCharacters id="creatchr" width="100%" height="100%"/>

        </s:NavigatorContent>

        <s:NavigatorContent width="100%" height="100%" label="Worlds">
            <s:TextArea id="txt3" x="55" y="10"
                        text="hello&#xd;I am testing this shit&#xd;hope it works"/>
            <s:Button id="sav" x="285" y="138" label="Save" click="sav_clickHandler(event)"/>
            <s:Button id="open" x="381" y="138" label="Open" click="open"/>
```

etc...

CreateCharaters.mxml (component)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:HGroup xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
          xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
          chromeColor="#0106BD" paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="0">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>


    <mx:ViewStack id="Characters" x="172" y="10" width="81" height="100%" backgroundColor="#030BB3"
                  chromeColor="#D7D7D8" paddingLeft="5" paddingRight="15">



        <s:NavigatorContent id="Hero" width="100%" height="95%" label="Main Charater">
            <s:HGroup width="100%" height="100%">
                <s:TextArea id="mainchar" bottom="0" width="80%" height="100%"
                            chromeColor="#7070FD">//this is the textarea I want to use
                    <s:text><![CDATA[
                        Name:
                        Surname:
                        Nickname:
                        Hair Color:
```

etc...

Any help please

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need binding in that case?

Your XML node is created and the `text` property is evaluated inside the same function so it should not be a problem. In other words, when the event handler is called, the current value of `text` will be copied inside your XML node but any future changes won't be reflected (you probably don't need that anyway since you save the XML file when clicking 'Save').

As for the chain in between curly braces, `{components.CreateCharacters.mainchar.text}` does not seem correct because `components.CreateCharacters` is a class reference, and not the reference to the component directly. Instead you should use `creatchr`;

I am not sure if the variable replacement inside XML supports `.`. Have you tried saving the `text` value inside a local or a class variable like this ?

```
    var currentText:String = creatchr.mainchar.text;
    <TXT>{currentText}</TXT>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however the variable var currentText stil gives me an undefined property on the mainchar.text. It reads the CreateCharacter bit fine but then gives me the undefined error on the mainchar bit. I don't understand why it is not picking it up. Could it be because mainchar is in a tabnavigator?

Comment: Not sure how `TabNavigator` works, but since you did not specify any `itemCreationPolicy`, `creatchr` should exist. What exactly is the error you get?

Comment: OK got it use the id not the file name. But now when I run the app I get a #1009 error cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. Stuck again

Comment: Do you an IDE with a debugger? Try to see which property is null.

Comment: It is the varialble currentText you suggested. If I remove that it works fine

Comment: Technically declaring `currentText` cannot throw an error. It is has to be one of `creatchr.mainchar.text`.

Comment: That would make sense, but I don't understand why that textarea would throw a null error. what does that mean?

Comment: Not ideal, but I moved all the code out of the component file and place it in my main.xml file then there is no error. This does not solve the problem, of pointing to the componenet but at least my app is working...